# A tag mysql-select faz sentido?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

Há a tag [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) com apenas 1 pergunta, e a tag [mysql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-select) com 21. Mas há algo de especial no `SELECT` do MySQL para que mereça uma tag específica? Não seria o caso de retagear tudo para [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select)?

**Nota:** acabei de perceber que também existem as tags [mysql-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-table), [mysql-order-by](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-order-by) e [mysql-update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-update). Na minha opinião, tudo se trata de SQL genérico, não vejo sentido no prefixo `mysql-` (me corrijam se eu estiver enganado).

Comment: Pior que algumas delas acho que fui eu que criei. Mas concordo com você, as mais genéricas são suficientes. Algumas poderiam até ser exterminadas. Dúvida: se tivermos uma tag `sql-table`, como distinguir se a pergunta é sobre uma tabela qualquer ou sobre o tipo `TABLE` do SQL Server (que não existe no MySQL)?

Comment: @bfavaretto Na minha opinião esse é justamente o caso em que uma tag específica se aplicaria. `sql-table` seria então sobre as tabelas normais do SQL, e `sql-server-table` sobre o tipo específico dessa plataforma. (P.S. `sql-server-table` ou `sqlserver-table`? Acabei de achar mais uma tag inconsistente - [`sqlserver-localdb`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver-localdb), enquanto a principal e derivadas são `sql-server*`)

Comment: tag sql-table + tag sqlserver fácil @bfavaretto

Comment: Na verdade existe um monte de tags assim, algumas repetidas com nomes EN e PT. Quem for criar tags deve ter mais consciência. Ter inúmeras tags em duplicata não é bom, fugi um pouco do assunto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi bom o @bigown trazer à tona esta discussão. Caso encerrado: [mysql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-select) foi mesclada com [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select), e agora é considerada um sinônimo. Tentativas de taguear uma pergunta como [mysql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-select) na verdade irão colocar na pergunta a tag principal.

Comment: E as outras na nota ali da pergunta?

Comment: Feito. Deixei [tag:order-by] sem o prefixo `sql-`, e as outras duas com o prefixo.

Answer (score 14):

Creio que não faz sentido tags que façam referências a tipos ou comandos específicos de determinadas tecnologias.

Já imaginou se tivéssemos tags para tudo? Exemplo: `classe-c#`, `string-java`, `heranca-c++`.

As tags deveriam ser um pouco mais "alto nível" do que isso, de forma a ajudar os usuários a filtrar e encontrar conteúdo.

Minha sugestão é remover todas as tags hiper-granulares porque elas são um tipo de ruído no site.

Comment: No SO em inglês existem essas tags mais granulares como `mysql-*`, mas aqui elas são muito mal utilizadas (lá eu não sei), o uso nas perguntas não é consistente. Se esta sua resposta tiver mais apoio, pegamos as nossas vassouras e resolvemos isso de uma vez :)

Comment: Eu acredito que a combinação de tags é o suficiente para a maioria dos casos descritos. Se usar [tag:mysql] e [tag:select] me parece claro o bastante sem nem mesmo usar na forma [tag:sql-select].

O mesmo serve para a grande maioria dos casos inclusive o mencionado pelo @bfavaretto :
se for algo específico do sql-server e usar [tag:sql-server] e [tag:sql-table] ficaria claro o suficiente qual a tecnologia que está utilizando.

Comment: Concordo - nós temos um sistema de _tags_, não de _sub-tags_. Se existe um mysql-select, vamos ter uma tag pra cada uma das instruções SQL suportadas pelo MySQL?

Comment: Se não tivesse essa resposta eu a teria escrito, pois é exatamente oque penso

Comment: @bfavaretto como você comentou no SO em inglês tem mesmo essa tags, porém acho que não precisamos levar em conta como são usadas lá, mas sim a quantidade de perguntas que temos pra determinadas tags, acho que o caso de usar tags mais especificas é quando uma tag genérica fica saturada de perguntas, exemplo: `mysql` tem 20 perguntas e `sql` tem 500, acho que aí se torna um caso de criarmos tags mais especificas para usar no lugar de `sql` já que nesse caso precisamos de um filtro mais otimizado para as perguntas

Answer (score 5):

Apesar da pergunta ser sobre uma *tag* específica vou fazer uma análise generalizada.

Uma *tag* parece não ajudar hoje porque tem poucas perguntas para classificar com ela. Mas e se ela for sendo usada cada vez mais e ela se tornar fundamental?

Então temos que analisar caso a caso se ela é exagero ou não.

Concordo plenamente que [classe-c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classe-c%23) seria um absurdo. O correto seria colocar [classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classe) e [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Passa a mesma ideia sem ser muito granular. Só faria sentido se tivesse especificidades que precisassem ser bem separadas. O que não é o caso.

O SO não possui a *tag* específica analisada. Mas possui a [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) (No SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), escrita de um jeito que consideramos errado já que são duas palavras. Esta talvez faça mais sentido.

`select` sozinha é ambígua. Existem "selects" que não são sobre SQL. Precisa ter como desambiguá-las. Já temos [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select). Então fica a questão se devemos ter a [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) ou se devemos apenas deixar as *tags* mais específicas. E nada impede usar [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) também.

Sou contra o uso apenas de [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) e [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select). Deveria ser [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) e [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select). A *tag* genérica induz a erro.

neste caso acho que a *tag* mais específica faz sentido e a mais genérica não. Mas acho que o espírito da outra resposta é indicar apenas que especificar o produto é junto com o recurso que está sendo discutido é exagero. Acredito que ela não seja contra a [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select).

A [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) me parece tão errada quanto a [mysql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-select).

Eu sequestrei a pergunta para adicionar este elemento para reviver o assunto e tomarmos uma decisão e porque acho que eles estão relacionados.

Parece haver apoio, pelo menos ninguém disse nada contra. Acho que cabe aos moderadores fazer alguma coisa agora.

Se precisar de ajuda para classificar as perguntas, é só falar.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o teu ponto de vista. Até sugeri em cima em comentário [tag:sql-table]+ [tag:sqlserver].